# Account Register with node express app continues loading in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with nodejs and I created a signup model for a user but after running in postman, there is no response or failure. I was just stucked there and got the following response in my terminal

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:12675) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

below is my model code

```
const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        fullName: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
            minlength: 1,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                validator: validator.isEmail,
                message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email'
            }
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
            minlength: 6
        },

        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        timestamp: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }

    }
);

AccountSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    const user = this
    const userObject = user.toObject()

    return _.pick(userObject, ['_id','fullName', 'email', 'token'])
}

AccountSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
    let user = this
    const today = new Date();
    const expirationDate = new Date(today);
    expirationDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);
    const token = jwt.sign({
        email: user.email,
        _id: user._id.toHexString(),
        exp: parseInt(expirationDate.getTime() / 1000, 10),
    }, 'process.env.JWT_SECRET').toString()

    user.token.push({
        token
    })

    return user.save().then(() => {
        return token
    })
}

AccountSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    let user = this

    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                user.password = hash
                next()
            })
        })
    } else {
        next()
    }
})

const Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema)
```

in my controller, I have this

cons

```
t _ = require('lodash')
const {Account} = require('../models/account')

exports.register = (req, res, next) => {
    const body = _.pick(req.body, ['fullName', 'email', 'password'])
    console.log(body)
    const account = new Account(body)
    account.save().then(() => {
        return account.generateAuthToken()
    }).then((token) => {
        res.header('Authorization', token).send(account)
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send(err)
    })
}
```

then my postman is like this

```
{
    "fullName": "Adie Olami",
    "email": "ugbe@gmail",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

let me also add, I am new to node and still learning so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is telling you that you are not correctly handling the situation where a promise rejects at some point in your code. Looking through what you have posted, I think the issue is with the following section:

```
return user.save().then(() => {
        return token
    })
```

You are not handling the possibility of a promise rejection from your call to user.save(). In order to fix this you need to add a catch block at the end:

```
... user.save()
    .then(() => {
        return token
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Log out the error to see what is going on for debugging purposes
        console.error(error);
        // Handle the error - in this case I've added a throw() but you could perhaps just return an empty token, or whatever you need for your use case.
        throw error;
    })
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am getting an error `"message": "Path `token` is required."`

Answer (score 3):

Very easy solution using `async/await`:

```
t _ = require('lodash')
const {Account} = require('../models/account')

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const body = _.pick(req.body, ['fullName', 'email', 'password'])
    console.log(body)
    const account = new Account(body)
try {
    await account.save();
    const accessToken = await account.generateAuthToken()
    res.header('Authorization', token).send(account)
 } catch(err) {
    res.status(400).send(err)
 }
}
```

Comment: what do I do with the `success` const defined

Comment: I am getting an error `"message": "Path `token` is required."`

Comment: @King it seems you are not passing proper arguments to the functions which are required by the method. See the documentation once again.